# No intellisense for Razor page @events

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2019 Community, but can't seem to get intellisense for @events on razor pages. Is there anything I need to turn on or install for this?

Here is an example of the intellisense that I am talking about:

[image]

And here is my desktop with no intellisense:

[image]

I do have Resharper installed as well, so not sure if that is the issue.

UPDATE: Looks like it is a Resharper conflict, when I disable Resharper it works. Does anyone know how I can have it working with Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue that has already been filed into [the JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-478594).